# Storing formulas in the database

Tags: mysql

I am looking to create a table in MySQL to store basic mathematical formulas in order to generated calculated results, such as:

result = (id_1 * some_stored_constant + id_2 * another_stored_constant) * id_5

Where ids are some timeseries values living in an existing table, so I could apply any of the stored formulas on the fly to any time point in the main table in order to generate the required results.

Any ideas what we would be the best structure to utilize? I would prefer to avoid storing the formulas a text and then parsing them into some other language - basically would prefer to do the calculation part natively in SQL.

Comment: You could store the parse tree as JSON.

Comment: I think "virtual column" is whatyou're looking for: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html . Alternatively, you can use stored procedures for (hardcoded) formulas. If you want to use different formulas for single rows based on some text-input, then I doubt this can be done: it would introduce great security risk to parse userinput inside your queries.